# How to send push notification via Amazon SNS in one API call?

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

Is it possible to send push notification in one API call by knowing `device token/registration id` and `platform application arn`?

I figured out that it can be done in 2 API calls (`CreatePlatformEndpoint` + `Publish`) but it seems there should be simpler way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no other way. You must first create the endpoint on SNS, then you will be able to send the notification by using it's ARN, and there is no API call to create and publish right away (at least not yet).

Check [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Publish.html) for reference

Comment: Ah, though I missed something because it seems like Amazon could themselves publish message to given device token.. Is there any alternative that support this?

Comment: Not that I know of. But you could skip SNS and send the requests directly to GCM/FCM, APNS or WNS, but then you'd have to implement all the logic